# Uniform distribution [0, 1], what is the distribution of $U^3$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $Y = U^3$

$P(Y \leq y) = P(U^3 \leq y) = P(U \leq y^{1/3}) = ?$

Am I approaching this question right? I am kinda stucked here and am wondering how do I determine the distribution for $U^3$.

Comment: You’re on the right track. You now need a formula for $P(U\le u)$ and insert $u=y^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(Y\leq y)=P(U^3\leq y)=P(U\leq y^{1/3})=\int_0^{y^{1/3}}dx=y^{1/3}.$ If you want the pdf, just differentiate and you get $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}$ when $0\leq y \leq 1$. Otherwise $0$.

Comment: This makes sense, but what form of distribution does it takes?

Comment: There isn't a particular name for this distribution, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: $P(U\le y^{1/3})$ also depends on what region $y$ is in.